# Re-Ordering User Favorites

Tags: cme

**Can users re-order their Favorites in Tridion?**

*I must have missed (or forgotten) this feature but a product manager pointed out we can (answer below).*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, in Content Manager Explorer's main list view, click on an item to move it up or down.

Moving items isn't possible in the navigation pane, which just shows the items.

[image: Order Favorites]

*This might be easy to miss if you mostly use the navigation pane*.

Comment: Good spot Alvin - I also missed this - I wonder how many other gems are available in the right pain that aren't in context menus on the left etc. :) (a OOTB rename would be sweet too!)

Comment: The functionality between navigation trees and the resulting view is slightly different, even in Windows Explorer (e.g. what should CTRL+A apply to?). Mostly the *ribbon toolbar* only activates on what you selected in the main, right view. Oh and not OOTB, but someone has implemented [favorites renaming](http://blogs.loginsoftconsulting.com/tridion/ability-to-rename-favorites-in-tridion/).